# How can I compute the sum of all i² for i between n and m?

Tags: linux, bash, math

How can I write a script to sum the squares of integers between two values `n` and `m`, meaning the sum of all `i`², where `i` runs from `n` to `m`?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Sounds like you'll just need a loop and some arithmetic expansion.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it:

```
#! /bin/sh
n=$1
m=$2
# Reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48080
sum=$(( (m * (m + 1) * (2 * m + 1) - (n - 1) * n * (2 * n - 1)) / 6 ))
echo $sum
```

Result:

```
./sum 3 7
135
```

Answer (score 1):

A rather *basic* approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0                      # initialise sum to zero
for i in $(seq $1 $2); do  # iterate from n to m
    sum=$((sum + i * i))   # add i² to sum
done
echo $sum                  # print sum
```

Call:

```
./sum.sh n m
```

There are other ways to write the loop though, [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110/how-do-i-write-a-for-loop-in-bash).

Answer (score 1):

Using Haskell, we can:

```
ghc -e 'sum [i*i | i <- [3..7]]'
```

or in bash script format:

```
#!/bin/bash
ghc -e "sum [i*i | i <- [$1..$2]]"
```